# C# Как вызвать не статическое событие из статического метода

Tags: c#

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        globalclik++;
    }
```

---

```
   public class CustomHotKey : HotKey
    {
        public CustomHotKey(string name, Key key, ModifierKeys modifiers, bool enabled)
        : base(key, modifiers, enabled)
        {
            Name = name;
        }

        private string name;
        public string Name
        {
            get { return name; }
            set
            {
                if (value != name)
                {
                    name = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged(name);
                }
            }
        }

        protected override void OnHotKeyPress()
        {

            if (Name == "1")
            {
         Здесь вызвать 
                Button_Click();
           Как это сделать ?     

            }


            base.OnHotKeyPress();
        }



    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Код в виде текста приложите. А по поводу вопроса - если объект не статичный, то инициализируете нужный объект, либо передаете ссылку на него и через этот объект обращаетесь, только модификатор доступа сделать не забудьте.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Спасибо большое. Решение простое. Сделал функцию  myfunk() заместо event.                                                                                    
       MainWindow ob = new MainWindow();
                    ob.myfunk();

Comment: Учтите, что при `new MainWindow()` вы делаете совершенно новое окно, которое не связано с тем, что вы видите на экране. Например если вы сделаете `ob.Show();`, то увидите 2 совершенно не связанных окна. Для того, что бы обратиться к основному окну, вы должны передать в нужный класс ссылку на него через конструктор. Вообще, у вас очень странный подход, предположу, что это вовсе WPF, а в нем такое неуместно...

Comment: @EvgeniyZ да это Wpf,можете помочь тогда, как сделать правильно

Comment: Правильно? Используйте привязки, команды, MVVM подход.

Comment: Можете помочь с этим? - Для того, что бы обратиться к основному окну, вы должны передать в нужный класс ссылку на него через конструктор.

Comment: `class MyClass { private MainWindows _window;  public MyClass(MainWindow window){ _windows = window; } }` Ну и дальше инициализируйте `var someClass = new MyClass(this);`, где `this` - это объект `MainWindow`. Все, во втором классе объект `_window` - это ссылка на основное окно.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ а теперь вызвать функцию не получается someClass.myfunk(); Потому что не содержит определения

Comment: https://pastenow.ru/3acfdf47031eaeb7bfc62cb04c2db819

Comment: я попробовал так  var someClass = new MyClass(this);
                    someClass.TextReload();

Comment: public void TextReload()
            {
                _window.myfunk();
            }

Comment: Мне вернуло _window пустую строку

Comment: Не копируйте просто так то, что вам говорят, вдумайтесь в код, подумайте что я вам показал. Почему у вас например на скрине используется `MyClass`, если это абстрактное название, которым я показал, что тут должен быть ваш класс, с вашем именем? Почитайте короче про конструкторы, про то, как передавать ссылки на объекты и все у вас должно встать на свои места.